# method for changing forms for metric and imperial (weight / height)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, servlets, web

I' asking the user to enter their weight but need to take metric and imperial into account.

I can think that the easiest / most user friendly way is to ask how they'd like to enter the weight/height via a drop down and then present the fields for them to fill in.

I tried this using jQuery but failed miserably, I also think I'm missing something fiarly important too as the final final will need to be passed to a servlet for db entry.

I'm using the below code to present the options and then tried a variety of different things which all failed, any help or advice would be welcomed, thanks!

```
    <label for "metricImperial">Metric or Imperial measurements?</label>
    <select id="metricImperial" name="metricImperial" class="required">
    <option value=""> -Select- </option>
        <option value="metric">Metric (kg) : Ex: 80kg</option>
        <option value="imperial">Imperial (lbs only) Ex: 190lbs<option>
        <option value="imperialSt">Imperial (St & lbs) Ex: 12st 8lbs<option>
    </select>
```

If the user selects st and lbs option I need to present two fields and also fire these values across to the servlet instead of one if it were just kg.

```
  <div id="metric"style="display:none;">
    <label for "weight">Weight</label>
    <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" type="text"  class= minlength="1"  placeholder="weight in kg only" /> <BR>
    </div>

    <div id="imperial"style="display:none;">
    <label for "weight">Weight</label>
    <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" type="text"  class= minlength="1"  placeholder="weight in lbs only"/> <BR>
    </div>

    <div id="imperialSt"style="display:none;">
    <label for "weight">Weight</label>
    <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" type="text"  class= minlength="1"  placeholder="st"/> <BR>
    <input id="weight2" type="text" name="weight2" type="text"  class= minlength="1"  placeholder="lb"/> <BR>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery(function($){
    $('#updateUserDetails').validate();

    $('#metric').hide(); //hide field
    $('#imperial').hide(); //hide field
    $('#imperialSt').hide(); //hide field 

    $("#metricImperial").change(function(){
        var metOrImp = $(this).val();//get the value from the dropdown
        alert(metOrImp);
        //switch, may not be the best but...
        switch(metOrImp){

        case 'metric' :
            ("#metric").show();
            ("#imperial").hide();
            ("#imperialSt").hide();
            break;
        case 'imperial' :
            ("#imperial").show();
            ("#metric").hide();
            ("#imperialSt").hide();
            break;
        case 'imperialSt' :
            ("#imperialSt").show();
            ("#metric").hide();
            ("#imperial").hide();
            break;
        }

    });


}
);


});
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jquery is wrong . You have missed $ signs all over and also the `jQuery(function($){` is unnecessary.. refer below code --> .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#metric').hide(); //hide field
    $('#imperial').hide(); //hide field
    $('#imperialSt').hide(); //hide field 

    $("#metricImperial").change(function(){
        var metOrImp = $(this).val();//get the value from the dropdown
        alert(metOrImp);
        //switch, may not be the best but...
        switch(metOrImp){

        case 'metric' :
            $("#metric").show();
            $("#imperial").hide();
            $("#imperialSt").hide();
            break;
        case 'imperial' :
            $("#imperial").show();
            $("#metric").hide();
            $("#imperialSt").hide();
            break;
        case 'imperialSt' :
            $("#imperialSt").show();
            $("#metric").hide();
            $("#imperial").hide();
            break;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: -.- Thank you! :)  While writing the questions I figured if the user selects st/lb Id * st by 14 and insert lb, same for kg but 2.2 - that way I'm only worried about storing a single value, does that make sense at all?

Comment: and, when I've converted this number (I figure it'd be easiest to do within the case), how might I pass it as a parameter to the servlet? Thanks again for all the help! :D

Comment: If you are computing it into one value then you can make one input which is hidden and then set its value to the computed value which you get from those two input . If you do this, name the hidden input as `weight` and replace the st input's name to something else . By doing so you would have to work only with the `weight` parameter in your servlet code .

Comment: ok, so stuck again :(  - I've set up the hidden fields and thought I could do soemthing like this but it's not updating, stupid reason?  $("#metricImperial").change(function(){
        var metOrImp = $(this).val();
        var updatedWeight = document.getElementById("weight");

        case 'metric' :
            $("#metric").show();

            updatedWeight.value = $("#metric").val() * 2.2;

Comment: First of all check you html code you need to re factor it top to bottom ,you have so many mistakes in it like you have used same id `weight` many times(id have to be unique for every element) and also written `type` attribute twice in the inputs .

Comment: Cleaned and refactored  many mistakes.  I think the problme is that I'm trying to update the value before the value has been entered into the field so calling it where I was is never going to work, correct?

Comment: yes you should set the hidden input value when you submit the form actually writing something like this (give an id to the form say #formid) `$( "#formid" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //compute the value from sb and lt
  // then set that computed value to the hidden field like 
  $("#hiddenfieldid").val(computedvalue);
  $("#formid").submit();   

});`

Comment: AND ALWAYS REMEMBER THE ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE IN ONE PAGE AND ONCE USED, THE SAME ONE SHOULD NEVER BE ASSIGNED TO SOME OTHER ELEMENT AGAIN !!!!!!!!!

Comment: could you take a peek at this please if you have a moment?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747271/updating-hidden-field-from-selection-and-posting-to-servlet-controller